# Scala: Dynamically get field names and values of an object?

Tags: scala

The following code works, but I want to improve it to be more generic.

```
trait Person{
  def name: String
  def age: Int
  val sex: String
  def listCustomFields:Unit = UtilClass(this)
}
case class Student(name: String, age: Int, sex:String) extends Person{
  // A custome field
  var school = "A"
}
case class Employee(name: String, age: Int, sex: String) extends Person{
  // Some custom fields
  var country:String = "Somewhere"
  val salary:Int = 123
}

case class UtilClass(claz:Person){
       claz match {
         case c:Student => println(s"Student with custom field ${c.school}")
           // Todo: How do I programatically list the custom fields without knowing their names ?
         case c:Employee => println(s"Employee with custom fields country: ${c.country}, salary: ${c.salary}")
       }
   // If only the following works
   //claz.getFields.map(f:Field => println(s"${f.getName} ${f.getValue}}"))

}
object GetArgumentValueByName extends App{

  val employee = new Employee("John", 32, "M")
  employee.country = "Earth"
  employee.listCustomFields
 // Output: Employee with custom fields country: Earth, salary: 123

}
```

I have been looking at `reflect.runtime.universe` but still don't understand how to do it. Essentially it is a matter of getting a list of fields and their values at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it that you want to do with the fields?  If you just want to be able to display them, override `toString`.  If you want to be able to do stuff with them, `unapply` is what you want, though the way you have this structured won't work.  Without knowing more about your intended usage, I would just recommend doing:

```
abstract class Person(name: String, age: Int, sex: String)
case class Student(name: String, age: Int, sex: String, school: String) extends Person(name, age, sex)
case class Employee(name: String, age: Int, sex: String, country: String, salary: Int) extends Person(name, age, sex)
```

Comment: My actual object of type Student or Employee would have quite a long list of custom fields that are unique to itself. I want to pass the field names and values to the UtilClass and do various processing depending on the values of those fields. As illustrated in the simplified `UtilClass` I want to print out all custom fields and their values  for each corresponding object.